# How to get Window under mouse properly?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf

As I have read, the way to get window under mouse is to use `WindowFromPoint` and that's what I did, but, it will always return the window handle of my window, if I place mouse over other window, it will always return my window handle!

Here is my code:

```
NativeMethods.POINT p;

if (NativeMethods.GetCursorPos(out p))
            {

                IntPtr hWnd = NativeMethods.WindowFromPoint(p);
                NativeMethods.GetWindowModuleFileName(hWnd, fileName, 2000);

string WindowTitle= fileName.ToString().Split('\\')[fileName.ToString().Split('\\').Length - 1];
// WindowTitle will never change, it will get my window only!

            }

////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

static class NativeMethods
        {

            [DllImport("user32.dll")]
            public static extern IntPtr WindowFromPoint(POINT Point);

            [DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError = true, CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
            public static extern uint GetWindowModuleFileName(IntPtr hwnd,
                StringBuilder lpszFileName, uint cchFileNameMax);

            [DllImport("user32.dll")]
            public static extern bool GetCursorPos(out NativeMethods.POINT lpPoint);


            [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
            public struct POINT
            {
                public int X;
                public int Y;

                public POINT(int x, int y)
                {
                    this.X = x;
                    this.Y = y;
                }

                public static implicit operator System.Drawing.Point(POINT p)
                {
                    return new System.Drawing.Point(p.X, p.Y);
                }

                public static implicit operator POINT(System.Drawing.Point p)
                {
                    return new POINT(p.X, p.Y);
                }
            }

            [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
            public struct RECT
            {
                public int Left;
                public int Top;
                public int Right;
                public int Bottom;
            }
        }
```

EDIT

As I am working in WPF, here is my try to use invoke in WPF:

```
void dispatcherOp_Completed(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            System.Threading.Thread thread = new System.Threading.Thread(
                new System.Threading.ThreadStart(
                  delegate()
                  {
                      System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherOperation
                        dispatcherOp = this.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(
                        System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherPriority.Normal,
                        new Action(
                          delegate()
                          {
                              NativeMethods.POINT p;
                              if (NativeMethods.GetCursorPos(out p))
                              {
                                  IntPtr hWnd = NativeMethods.WindowFromPoint(p);
                                  NativeMethods.GetWindowModuleFileName(hWnd, fileName, 2000);

                                  uint processID = 0;
                                  uint threadID = GetWindowThreadProcessId(hWnd, out processID);
                                  string filename= Process.GetProcessById((int)processID).MainModule.FileName;
                              }

                          }
                      ));
                      dispatcherOp.Completed -= new EventHandler(dispatcherOp_Completed);
                      dispatcherOp.Completed += new EventHandler(dispatcherOp_Completed);
                  }
              ));


            thread.Start();
        }
```

Comment: Never ignore the return value of winapi functions.  Not initializing the StringBuilder also sounds like an accident waiting to happen.

Answer (score 2):

`GetWindowModuleFileName` is [restricted](http://support.microsoft.com/?id=228469#appliesto) to the calling process, it will not work if you pass a `HWND` belonging to another.

Instead you could use the `HWND` & p/invoke `GetWindowThreadProcessId()` to get a process ID then you can `Process.GetProcessById(processId).MainModule.FileName;`.

Comment: Please see EDIT above, I tried to follow what you've said, but now, I got "A 32 bit processes cannot access modules of a 64 bit process." do you know a solution for this ? Thanks.